# JavaScript library fails due to undefined variable however it only happens half the page loads

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript project to build a modal window to show project tasks in.  IN the modal window is several JS libraries for things such as popovers, edit-in-place, date picker, markdown, @mentions, scroll-bars, and lots more.

The project is a mess right now but its my first big JS project and its coming along nicely.

Basically there will be Task lists and when a task is clicked on, it will load the task data and initialize the libraries for the task into a modal window.

All tasks share the same modal in the DOM so when a modal is closed it destroys the initiated libraries and resets the data.  The next task record clicked will then redo the build cycle for the modal.

I recently also added the ability to have the task modal open by appending
 `#task-modal=1414135033731` to the URL.  Where the numbers will be the task record database ID number.

My issue is that about 50% of the time when I load the page everything loads perfect with no console errors and all is working great.

The other 50% of the loads halt with a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined  
In file jquery-datepicker-foxrunsoftware.js:440
```

Line 440 of that file which is the Date Picker calendar library I use shows this code...

line 440 in code below is this one `var width = tbl.offsetWidth;`

```
  /**
   * Internal method which lays out the calendar widget
   */
  layout = function(el) {
    var options = $(el).data('datepicker');
    var cal = $('#' + options.id);
    if (options.extraHeight === false) {
      var divs = $(el).find('div');
      options.extraHeight = divs.get(0).offsetHeight + divs.get(1).offsetHeight;  // heights from top/bottom borders
      options.extraWidth = divs.get(2).offsetWidth + divs.get(3).offsetWidth;     // widths from left/right borders
    }
    var tbl = cal.find('table:first').get(0);
    var width = tbl.offsetWidth;                 // line 440 
    var height = tbl.offsetHeight;
    cal.css({
      width: width + options.extraWidth + 'px',
      height: height + options.extraHeight + 'px'
    }).find('div.datepickerContainer').css({
      width: width + 'px',
      height: height + 'px'
    });
  },
```

[image]

---

The console error shows this below when clicked on...

[image]

---

As mentioned it happens like half the time and other times it works fine without showing this error.

My mess of an app is way to many lines of code to post here but I have uploaded a demo to show it in action here

Demo: removed

When you view the demo, view the console.  It might all load find  but then keep reloading page and you will eventually get the error.  Sometimes I will get the error over and over and over again!

I Mam really stuck and I need help getting past this.

I don't want to have to use a new date picker library but at this point I might have to if I cannot get rid of this error.

---

Please help if you can I have been stuck for weeks on this now!

Even ideas for things to try would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your datepicker hasn't been initialized and your `'#' + options.id` lookup fails because it doesn't exist yet.

There's something asynchronous going on, and you're not waiting for it (or datepicker is just a crappy plugin, I don't deal with jQuery too much, thank goodness).

Comment: in the error list one of them takes me to code using AJAX to load the data and defferends.  Perhaps I need to try and init my datepicker lib in that area.  What is strange to me is how it randomly works sometimes and other times doesnt

Comment: When I click to open modal I load data for task from a task list in DOM.  When I load modal from hash in URL it makes AJAX request so it does seem to only happen when loading with AJAX.  So that is some progress thanks

Comment: im gonna go ahead and accept.  Its not a solution but I think the issue is identified and Ill play with that.  thanks